# SocketServer Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, web, websocket

So I found the following sample code which allows for a basic python HTTP server to be established at a given url and port. I am quite inexperienced with web servers and am trying to create handlers for certain GET requests to this server. However, I cannot figure out how to actually create handlers for a GET request made by another computer when accessing this URL remotely. Any suggestions?

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
"""
The RequestHandler class for our server.

It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
override the handle() method to implement communication to the
client.
"""

def handle(self):
    # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
    self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
    print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
    print self.data

    # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
    self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
HOST, PORT = "url" , PORT

# Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

# Activate the server; this will keep running until you
# interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: there are higher level frameworks, that easily let you define functions to be called, for certain requested paths, bottle, flask, django, tornado

Comment: So how would I go about implementing them in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is **very** simple example of how it could work.  You would start this and call it with this, for example:

```
curl -i 'http://localhost:5001/foo/bar?foo=bar' -X POST -d '{"Foo":"Bar"}'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Some response%
```

It is missing **tons** of things, but this should at least give you some sort of idea.

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print self.data
        self.parse_request(self.data)
        func, args = self.path.split("/", 1)
        args = args.split("/")
        resp = getattr(self, func)(*args)
        self.request.sendall("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
        self.request.sendall("\n")
        self.request.sendall(resp)

    def parse_request(self, req):
        headers = {}
        lines = req.splitlines()
        inbody = False
        body = ''
        for line in lines[1:]:
            if line.strip() == "":
                inbody = True
            if inbody:
                body += line
            else:
                k, v = line.split(":", 1)
                headers[k.strip()] = v.strip()
        method, path, _ = lines[0].split()
        self.path = path.lstrip("/")
        self.method = method
        self.headers = headers
        self.body = body
        self.path, self.query_string = self.path.split("?")

    def foo(self, *args):
        print self.path
        print self.query_string
        print self.body
        print self.headers
        print self.method
        return "Some response"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer(("localhost", 5001), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```